# SELECT CURSOR: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -10

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, jpa, oracle12c, nativequery

I have a Spring Boot application with a JpaRepository which contains a native query with this structure:

```
SELECT a, b, c, CURSOR( SELECT ... FROM ... ), ...
FROM ...
WHERE ...
```

And I'm getting the following exception:

> org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -10

I am using `Oracle12cDialect`, and I think the problem comes from the `CURSOR` in my query, but I don't know how to solve it. Also, I cannot modify the query, I've been ordered to try to implement it as it is.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

This SQL returns column of type CURSOR, which is a handle to another SQLs' resultSet. I do not believe SpringBoot support this.

This is a trick how to return data having more than two dimensions.

You have to either use JSON object as 4th column, or use ah-hoc query for each row for 4th column. To query that detail/child object.